# How to show an interface to select points in python?

Tags: python, interface, conways-game-of-life

Well, I'm programming Conway's game of life in python, and although my program works, the way the user gives the initial points is writing the coordinates of each point.

I want an interface that shows the points with integer coordinates of the cartesian plane, let me select some with the mouse and finally give back the points I selected as tuples(or lists, doesn't matter).
Should I download some kind of program or there is a module that has such functionality?

I would also like to ask for some "program" that instead of points, graphs pixels, like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2vgICfQawE). Right now, I'm just using matplotlib to graph, but I think it looks cooler with pixels.

Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I didn't want to post the code, for being so long, but here it is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from string import split

reglas=raw_input("Enter rule of the game(Ej.:B3/23)")
Q=[letra for letra in reglas]
m=Q.index("/")
born, keep=[int(i) for i in Q[1:m]], [int(i) for i in Q[m+1:]]
discard=[x for x in range(1,9) if x not in keep and x not in born]
livecells=set()
a=raw_input("Enter a coordinate (a,b), which will be a living cell. This program will keep you asking coordinates until you decide to stop. To stop, instead of a coordinate, enter stop")
a=tuple([int(float(i)) for i in split(a)])

livecells.add(a)
while True: 
    b=raw_input("Another coordinate")
    if b!="stop":
        b=tuple([int(i) for i in split(b)])
        livecells.add(b)
    else:
        break

def whoisnear(a,b):
    return set([(a+1,b),(a+1,b+1),(a+1,b-1),(a,b+1),(a,b-1),(a-1,b+1),(a-1,b),(a-1,b-1)])
def firstcoordinate(x,y):
    return x
def secondcoordinate(x,y):
    return y
def rectanglearea(c,d,e,f):
    candidates=set()
    for i in range (c-3,d+3):
        for j in range(e-3,f+3):
            candidates.add((i,j))
    return candidates 
Q=[x for (x,y) in livecells]
W=[y for (x,y) in livecells]

plt.plot(Q,W,'ro')
plt.axis([min(Q)-1,max(Q)+1,min(W)-1,max(W)+1])
plt.savefig('0.png')
plt.show()
repetitions=0
minx=min([firstcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells])
maxx=max([firstcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells])
miny=min([secondcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells])
maxy=max([secondcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells])

for j in range(1,30):
    try:
        X={firstcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells}
        Y={secondcoordinate(*i) for i in livecells}
        D=rectanglearea(min(X),max(X),min(Y),max(Y))
        Todiscard=set()
        Toadd=set()
        for i in D:
            K=whoisnear(*i) & livecells
            n=len(K)
            if n in discard:
                Todiscard.add(i)
            elif n in born:
                Toadd.add(i)


        livecells=livecells-Todiscard

        livecells=livecells|Toadd
        firstcords=[x for (x,y) in livecells]
        secondcords=[y for (x,y) in livecells]
        plt.plot(firstcords,secondcords,'ro')
        plt.axis([minx-30,maxx+30,miny-30,maxy+30])
        plt.savefig(str(j)+'.png')
        plt.close()
    except ValueError:
        print j,livecells
        break
```

Comment: Can you provide your code, I may be able to supply some basic interface

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. See [What Topics Can I Ask About Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Rory Daulton I don't think my question is opinion-based, I  just wish one single program that do what I want, I'm not asking which is the best program. Of course, I'd prefer that it be simple, cause I'm very new in programming, but that is a matter of opinion. I just would like alternatives.

Comment: Try moving to another interface, such as Tkinter or pygame. Drawing is easy and user input is not harder.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is a script I developed to extend the `pygame` module. I don't want to write your code for you but this should get you started! My code is well documented and should be easy for you to understand. Good luck!

**Screen Module**

```
import pygame, sys, ctypes, os
from pygame.locals import *
import random

class Screen:
    '''
        --Screen module for handling the pygame display module...
    '''

    def __init__(self, resolution=(640,480), caption=None, transparent=False, icon=None, flags=0):
        '''
            --Grabs and sets the args
            --Grabs the center of the screen based on the monitor resolution
            --Creates a new instance of screen
            '''

        self.resolution = resolution
        self.flags = flags

        if caption:
            self.setCaption(caption)
        if icon:
            self.setIcon(icon)

        self.monitorCenter = self.getCenterScreen(self.getMonitorSize())

        self.centerScreen()

        self.transparent = transparent

        self.screen = self.setScreen()

    def update(self):
        pygame.display.update()


    def setIcon(self, icon):
        '''
            --sets the icon at the icon position on 
                the pygame window. Maintain origonal
                .jpg location

            Usage:
                --self.setIcon(self, 'coolIcon.jpg'
                '''

        try:
            self.icon = icon
            icon = pygame.image.load(icon)
        except:
            self.icon = None
            return
        pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    def setScreen(self):
        '''
            --creates and returns default pygame window...

            Usage:
                --screen.setScreen()
            '''
        if self.transparent:
            return pygame.display.set_mode(self.resolution, self.flags).convert_alpha()
        return pygame.display.set_mode(self.resolution, self.flags)

    def setCaption(self, caption):
        '''
            --Sets window caption as (caption)...

            Usage:
                --screen.setCaption("My Game!")
            '''

        pygame.display.set_caption(caption)

    def didResize(self):
        info = pygame.display.get_surface()
        return info

    def setMousePos(self, pos):
        '''
            --Sets the mouse at [pos]...

            Usage:
                --screen.setMousePos((250,250))
            '''

        pygame.mouse.set_pos(pos)


    def setScreenPos(self, position):
        '''
            --Sets the windows window argument position to (position)

            Usage:
                --screen.setScreenPos((250,250))
            '''

        os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = str(position[0])+','+str(position[1])

    def getMonitorSize(self):
        '''
            --Returns the actual resolution of the active display

            Usage:
                --screen.getMonitorSize()
            '''

        user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        screenSize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
        return screenSize

    def getCenterScreen(self, res):
        '''
            --Returns the center of the screen based on the monitor 
            --resolution [res] / 2 - window resolution [self.resolution] / 2

            Usage:
                --screen.getCenterScreen((1365,782))
            '''

        center = ((res[0]/2)-self.resolution[0]/2), ((res[1]/2)-self.resolution[1]/2)
        return center

    def centerScreen(self):
        '''
            --sets the center of the pygame window to the 
            --center of the monitor
            --centerScreen() needs to be called before 
            --setScreen() in order for it to center...

            Usage:
                --screen.centerScreen()
            '''

        centerScreen = self.getCenterScreen(self.getMonitorSize())
        self.setScreenPos(centerScreen)

    def getFlags(self):
        '''
            --Returns the flags associated the the active screen...

            Usage:
                --screen.getFlags()
            '''

        return self.getScreenSurface().get_flags()

    def getScreenSurface(self):
        '''
            --Returns the surface object of the active screen...

            Usage:
                --screen.getScreenSurface()
            '''

        return pygame.display.get_surface()

    def getCaption(self):
        '''
            --Returns the current caption associated with the active screen...

            Usage:
                --screen.getCaption()
            '''

        return pygame.display.get_caption()[0]

    def getMousePos(self):
        '''
            --Returns the current mouse position [x,y] on the window...

            Usage:
                --screen.getMousePos()
            '''
        return pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def closeScreen(self):
        '''
            --De-initializes the screen object...

            Usage:
                --screen.closeScreen()
            '''

        pygame.display.quit()

    def initScreen(self):
        '''
            --Re-initializes the screen object...

            Usage:
                --screen.initScreen()
            '''

        pygame.display.init()

    def resize(self, size):
        '''
            --Creates a new screen instance with resolution of (size)...

                --Overwrites the self.screen object with new size
                --Grabs the New Size, current Caption, and current Flags
                --Closes the current screen instance
                --Creates a new screen instance
                --Places the center of the screen at the center of the monitor
                --Checks if flags contains FULLSCREAN if so it toggles
                --Creates a new display instance with resolution[x,y], and flags(flags)
                --Sets the screen caption

                Usage:
                    --screen.resize((640,480))
            '''

        self.resolution = size
        caption = self.getCaption()
        self.flags = self.getFlags()

        self.closeScreen()
        self.initScreen()

        self.centerScreen()

        if self.flags == FULLSCREEN:
            print self.flags
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.resolution),self.flags^FULLSCREEN)
        else:
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.resolution),self.flags)
        self.setCaption(caption)

    def toggleFullscreen(self):
        '''
            Module for toggeling between default resolution and fullscreen...

                --Grabs the current screen CAPTION, FLAGS, and MOUSE POSITION
                --Grabs the current surface size
                --Checks to see what resolution the screen is currently at and toggles it
                --Overwrites the self.screen object with new size
                --Closes the current screen instance
                --Creates a new screen instance
                --Places the center of the screen at the center of the monitor
                --Creates a new display instance with resolution[x,y], and flags^FULLSCREEN(toggle)
                --Sets the new screens caption with old caption

                Usage:
                    --screen.toggleFullscreen()
            '''

        caption = self.getCaption()
        self.flags = self.getFlags()

        surface = self.getScreenSurface()
        size = surface.get_width(), surface.get_height()
        if size == self.resolution:
            size = self.getMonitorSize()
        else:
            size = self.resolution

        self.closeScreen()
        self.initScreen()

        self.centerScreen()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size),self.flags^FULLSCREEN)
        self.setCaption(caption)
        self.setIcon(self.icon)

class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, screen, size=(16,16)):
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = self.screen.screen
        self.size = size
        self.grid = tuple(((x,y) for y in range(0, self.screen.resolution[1], size[1]) for x in range(0, self.screen.resolution[0], size[0])))
        self.elements = self.create_elements()
        self.active_elements = []

    def create_elements(self):
        l = {}
        for x,y in self.grid:
            if x in l:
                l[x].update({y:None})
            else:
                l[x] = {0:None}
        return l
    def set_grid(self, new_size):
        self.grid = ((x,y) for y in range(0, self.screen.resolution[1], new_size[1])for x in range(0, self.screen.resolution[0], new_size[0]))

    def check_active(self):
        self.active_elements = [i for i in [self.elements[x][y] for x,y in self.grid] if i != None]

    def add_element(self, (x,y), color):
        self.elements[x][y] = (color, (x*self.size[0],y*self.size[1], self.size[0], self.size[1]), 0)
        self.check_active()

    def remove_element(self, (x,y)):
        self.elements[x][y] = None
        self.check_active()

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x, y in self.grid:
            pygame.draw.line(self.surface, (255,255,255), (x, 0), (x, self.screen.resolution[0]), 1)
            pygame.draw.line(self.surface, (255,255,255), (0, y), (self.screen.resolution[0], y), 1)

        for elem in self.active_elements:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, *elem)
```

**Main Code**

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.constants import *
from PyScreen.screen import Screen, Grid
pygame.init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_display = Screen(caption='Conways Game Of Life', resolution=(1280, 720))
    grid = Grid(my_display, (16,16)) #second parameter is the grid size
    grid.add_element((0, 0), (255,255,255)) #anytime you want to add a cell
    grid.add_element((16,16), (255,255,255))
    grid.remove_element((0, 0)) #when you want to remove a cell
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        my_display.screen.fill((0,0,0))
        grid.draw_grid()
        my_display.update()
```