# Trying to plot some data in matplotlib with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to simulate Conway's Game of Life in python([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412263/how-to-show-an-interface-to-select-points-in-python) is some of the code), and now I need to handle the ouput. Right now, I'm just plotting points in matplotlib but I want something like what [this](http://nicoguaro.github.io/) guy did(That script shows error in my PC but it generates the images anyway). I understand that the code I am looking for is:

```
plt.imshow(A, cmap='bone', interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
```

and that A is a numpy array alike a matrix with just True and False as entries.
By the way, I've already realized that instead of True and False I can put 1's and 0's.
I have the data of living cells as a set of points ([(x1,y1),(x2,y2),....,(xn,yn)]) of the plane(coordinates all integers). As you can see, my script is finite(it uses a for loop until 30), so I preset the plots' axis before the loop...for example, the minimum x coordinate of the plots is the minimum coordinate of the initial points minus 30, assuring then that all the points are visible in the last image.
To represent each configuration, I had the idea to do:

```
SuperArray=np.zeros(maxx+30,maxy+30) 
for (i,j) in livecells:
    SuperArray[i,j]=1
```

But that idea won't work, because the indices of SuperArray are all positives, and my coordinates maybe negative. To solve this I was thinking in translate ALL of the points in livecells so their coordinates be positive. I would do that by adding |minx|+30 to the x coordinate and |miny|+30 to the y coordinate
of each (x,y) in livecells...I haven't put it in practice yet, but it seems too complicated and memory consuming...Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: The link to your code doesn't work.